# Which layout to use for popup with more widgets - kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy

I have a gameover popup with title, label with score, label that tells you to insert your name, textinput next to it and two buttons at the popup bottom. I tried using `BoxLayout` before but it didn't look how I wanted so I changed it to `GridLayout` but the result is weird. The main problem is that widgets don't cover the whole popup but leave about 30 pixel spacing at the bottom. 
Here is a screenshot of the popup: http://postimg.org/image/5px41imkd/

.py part of code for the popup:

```
def show_gameover_popup(self, *args):
    content = GridLayout(rows=3)
    score_label = Label(text="Your score:  {}".format(self.score), font_size=20)
    name_label = Label(text="Your name:", font_size=20)
    play_button = Button(text="Play again",
                         font_size=20,
                         size_hint_y=None,
                         height=55,
                         background_color=(0.012, 0.227, 0.11, 0.4))
    empty_label = Label(text=" ", font_size=20)
    name_input = TextInput(multiline=False, font_size=20, size_hint_y=None,height=50)
    exit_button = Button(text="Exit",
                         font_size=20,
                         on_press=exit,
                         size_hint_y=None,
                         height=55,
                         background_color=(0.012, 0.227, 0.11, 0.4))

    content.add_widget(score_label)
    content.add_widget(empty_label)
    content.add_widget(name_label)
    content.add_widget(name_input)
    content.add_widget(play_button)
    content.add_widget(exit_button)

    p = GameOverPopup(content=content)
    play_button.bind(on_press=p.dismiss)
    p.open()
```

and .kv:

```
<GameOverPopup>:
    size_hint: .5, .4
    title: "You lost!"
    title_size: 20
    background_color: 1,1,1,0.5
    background: "popup.png"
    auto_dismiss: False
```

I do have the `GameOverPopup` class and all the imports. Everything works as it should, the only problem I have is with how it looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in .kv, you specify the GameOverPopup height as a percentage of the screen height and width (size_hint: .5, .4), but the content height (the buttons and labels etc.) in pixels. That means there is no guarantee at all that the content will fit the popup area, hence the gap.

In order for the GridLayout to size the children vertically, you would need to specify a 'size_hint_y' for the children  and not hard-code their height.